# Gated checkin at client side

Tags: tfs

We are doing gated-in using TFS. So, what happens is whenever there is check-in, the build process will run for an hour in the build server and after that it will report the build failure results, even it is a simple issue.

If there is a four simple issues, each issue shown after an hour means on each issue fix, the other issue is shown up, then it takes four hours for him.

I would like to know whether, there is any tool which can validate style-cop issues and code-analysis at client side (developer machine) not in the build server. when the developer triggers the check-in.

The process should be like,

Developer check-in the code,
validated for style-cop and code-analysis issues at client side (developer machine),
once client side (developer machine) validation is over then the entire code changes has to be checked in to the build server.

Answer (score 1):

You should look into [check-in policies](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181459%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), as these are checks which automatically run before being allowed to check in.

Either create your own [custom check-in policy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb668980.aspx) (old article, but still good introduction) or possibly look at [this policy which can run StyleCop checks](http://sourceanalysispolicy.codeplex.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Yes exactly i suggest you to execute Style Cop in Visual Studio , right click on your solution and select link `Run Style Cop`. (Same Case for Code Analysis, click link '`Run Code Analysis on Solution`')
Ensute that you have copied `Setting File Style Cop` in the root of each project.
For Code Analysis, right click on your project, select properties, access to Code Analysis Tab.

You don't need to create Shelveset on server with Gated Check In, but every developper must realize this work

Comment: Right that is a manual process, sometimes what happens people miss that or some people who might have joined the team newly. so it will end up build failure. To avoid that I wanted an automated process. please suggest any tool for that

Comment: people must check his code before check in Prakash, if you use Scrum as methodology, you can create stand up every morning and speak about (It's human failure, not problem about process or platform)

Comment: sure I agree and I've no issues with the process. but instead of right click and doing the style cop and code analysis. I expect a tool which does both the thing while the developer check in the code and that too before the code goes into build server.

Comment: I suggest you tool as NCrunch, permit to excute analysis tool and as result you have different reports, but it's very contraignant because every save or compile process execute tool. link : http://www.ncrunch.net/

Comment: You can also try with Build Events - Post Build (Properties of your project)

Comment: Thanks Aghilas Yakoub. Let me try those solutions

Comment: Happy to help you Prakash